# Error with CMU Serif font

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}
  text
\end{document}
```

but receive this error

```
l.17 \setmainfont{CMU Serif}

?
```

in miktex-maketfm.log it says :

```
2017-10-08 23:57:03,239+0200 INFO  miktex-maketfm - starting with command line: miktex-maketfm -v "CMU Serif"
2017-10-08 23:57:03,259+0200 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-10-08 23:57:03,259+0200 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-makemf.exe --verbose "CMU Serif"
2017-10-08 23:57:03,449+0200 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
2017-10-08 23:57:03,449+0200 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-hbf2gf.exe -g "CMU Serif" 300
2017-10-08 23:57:03,600+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font "CMU Serif".
```

Previously I had problems compiling fontspec; it seemed that got solved by updating miktex, but the two may still be connected. Thank you.

Comment: maketfm should never have been called, you presumably had an error earlier?

Comment: You can't call `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` if the font is not installed as a system font.

Comment: @egreg Shouldnt the system ask to install the font? In case not, how do I install it. 
(at)david I'm compiling just that code, but there was this :
    ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")))Running miktex-makemf.exe...

Comment: You can install the font in windows just by dragging it into the fonts folder.

Comment: Miktex won't install such a font on-the-fly, but you can install it with the package manager (package cm-unicode).

Comment: @egreg Your suggestion solved the problem, can you write an Answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the call `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` only if the font is installed as a system font (or with LuaLaTeX). How to do the installation is system dependent.

Otherwise you can call the fonts “by font name”:

```
\setmainfont{cmun}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*rm,
  ItalicFont=*ti,
  BoldFont=*bx,
  BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]
\setsansfont{cmun}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*ss,
  ItalicFont=*si,
  BoldFont=*sx,
  BoldItalicFont=*so,
]
\setmonofont{cmun}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*btl,% light version
  ItalicFont=*bto,%  light version
  BoldFont=*tb,
  BoldItalicFont=*tx,
]
```

For the Typewriter Text font, also `tt` and `it` can be used instead of `btl` and `bto` (if you don't plan to use boldface monospaced)

Comment: On Fedora: `dnf install texlive-cm-unicode`.